# A question about using ferrite chokes in a data-acquisition system

Tags: ferrite

I'm planning to buy [this flat ferrite choke][1] for ribbon cable to suppress suspected EMI on a data acquisition's multiplexer.

I have no experience on signal integrity. Bu the system setup is basically like this(On the right side the system is single-ended earth grounded):

Instead of adding chokes to each BNC I thought it would be easier to use just one flat core for the ribbon cable since it conveys the signals to ADC insdie the PC.

Which would be a better option? To apply chokes to each BNC cables or to use one flat ferrite core around the ribbon cable? I also couldnt find any passive chokes for 50 Ohm coaxial BNC cables in the market until now, neither info how to install them.

I'm having random glitches sometimes. By random I mean 2 or 3 times in 30 minutes acquisition. And this is not every time. By glitch I mean at some point suddenly all the channels are affected. So it is almost impossible to observe this by scope because I don't know when the noise will hit.

Comment: It's not that easy. There's a lot of different types of noises, and which one is relevant for your signal can't be said just by looking at your system from this afar.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Assume the noise is EMI interference. I want to check of the effect of using ferrites since it is impossible to see this noise by scope since it is extremely random no one knows when it will hit. Is there a typical solution for EMI related noise? I dont know how to connect a choke to a BNC and how big  should the toroid be. Couldnt find any info

Comment: "EMI interference" tells nothing about how the noise relates to your signal, what kind of amplitude and frequency distribution it follows, how or where it comes into your system and what it does to your sampling … sorry, can't help you on this level of information :(

Comment: @MarcusMüller I added more info for you and others. Please see edit. Maybe it helps to clarify my question.

Comment: definitely helps!

Comment: @doncarlos Put on your detective cap. and determine the precise location and cause of MUX / DATA process to isolate logic fault and cause. e.g. external or internal for each  box/card/signal/software/ IRQ? pseudo-random yet periodic null? must be almost-synchronous to something.( auto-zero?) ...  Did you contact tech support?

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 Before digging in possible hardware issues, I want to be sure if it is a software bug or not. So I was thinking to make the daq by two different software simultaneously sampling same analog inputs using BNC splitters. If both software gives same error I would conclude it should be hardware or noise. It will take so long time to achieve this because the issue is very random.

Comment: Got a soldering iron nearby?  When my bathroom fan shuts off in next room by timer. my HDMI monitor goes blank for a 1/2 second,. It does this only recently but every time. Not the same but synchronous. Yours is perhaps too. just 0.1 pulse per minute.   Weller thermal tips were notorious for glitches every 5~10 minutes.

Comment: Not a soldering iron but in the same room 12 meters far away there is a VFD which is controlling  3-phase AC motor in the same room. But they are  continuously running. One output of the daq board through BNC connector goes to VFD through an isolation amplifier. But the error Im getting some days and some times like 2 3 times in 30 minutes. Is there a possibility another utility somewhere else(another building stage ect.) is affecting the earth ground? The daq system is single ended earth grounded.

Comment: pleisiosynchronous means "almost" synchronous or like when all the planets line up or all your data is masked by some deadtime in a high speed loop with 2 different frame rates and jitter.  Have your shorted all your inputs to Vref to analyze the problem?

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 How about plugging a vacuum cleaner nearby and switch it on and off to see if there is an effect on GND? Is it a good way to provoke a noise intentionally?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49179/discussion-between-don-carlos-and-tony-stewart-ee-since-75).

Answer (score 2):

All channels simultaneously get a value of 0 – that's most definitely not EMI, or any other type of what I'd call "noise".

That's a problem with your sampling hardware. Now, this might be anything – from a driver bug to a hardware fault, to samples not being fetched before some buffer runs over to some problems with a on-board power supply, or, and that's my current guess: a faulty connector somewhere that randomly makes the "BNC box" power off.

Generally, if you really just need 6 channels, your bandwidths are this low and you don't calibrated voltage readings, but just relative values: Try replacing the PCI DAQ card with a simple multichannel sound card.

A single 16bit ADC that gets multiplexed across a few 4kS/s channels? That's really not that great – you can actually build that with something as cheap as an arduino. Still, it's probably more time- and cost-efficient to not build something like that yourself, but try with widely available DACs – of which soundcards are the cheapest ones, and perform surprisingly well.

Comment: BNC box is not power supplied. Do you mean a connection problem between the ribbon and the BNC box? The thing is it is not possible to change the daq board for some reason, all the software written for this and libraries ect. But is there a way to log this data in parallel(using a data logger or arduino something easy to read at least one channel and log the data for 30 minutes) and prove if it is a software bug or hardware problem? thanks

Comment: how should I know? I didn't write your software!